# TCPDF unable to output file by saving. Path on Mac?

Tags: php, path, tcpdf, lampp

I checked some similar questions here, but i didn't got an answer, solving my problem.

I use TCPDF to generate a PDF with PHP.

When I use the `$pdf->Output($file_total, 'I');`
it's all good and the file is shown in Browser.

If I use the save to localhost option `$pdf->Output($file_total, 'F');` I get this error:

"failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/tcpdf_min/include/tcpdf_static.php on line 1821"
"TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file"

The Path I set for saving the PDF file is: "/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/files/2021"

What am I doing wrong? is my path wrong?

The forced saving `$pdf->Output($file_total, 'D');` works just fine, so i must doing something wrong with the path on mac...
please help!

Thanks

Comment: @KJ that the answer I saw already. Th ob_clean() didn’t work for me. I do something wrong with “yourpath/output.pdf” the path I type is “/opt/lampp/htdosc/project/files/2021” and I get the error above. I need the pdf to be stored in this particular folder… any ideas what am I doing wrong?!

Comment: @KJ thanks for your answer. It's sort of Virtual machine. The full path to the folder 2021 is "nfs://192.168.64.2/opt..." it doesn't work also.  I also tried with the "192.168.64.2/opt..." - also nothing... I'm missing something with the path. I printf the path variables and they look the way they should... I just need to know how to set the path to this virtual LAMPP machine on mac...

Comment: @KJ, ok I tried with "http://localhost:8080/project..." and now i do not get the first part of the error anymore (the line 1821), but I still get "TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: http://localhost:8080/project/files/2021/output.pdf" any idea?!

Comment: @KJ I am logged as admin... but i'll check. All other output options (forced save "D", show in browser "I" and string "S") are working properly... Only the save lags... I'm really baf...

Comment: @KJ so i change the properties of all folders in the lampp machine to everyone "write and read"... nothing happened.

Comment: @KJ YOU ARE A Genius!!!! The problem was the folder permissions!!! Now it works like a charm! Thanks man! you saved me!!! So can you write an answer with both parts in it : path is "localhost:8080/projects..." and that all folders must have permissions set to "read/write" for all users. So I could set your the green check as Answer, so you could get some points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments we both went through possible reasons such as finding an absolute rather than relative location and checking out folder permissions for non admin process as that was also suspected. Thus between us the conclusion was:-

use address as

`"localhost:8080/projects..."`

and ensure target folder was set to permissions

`"read/write"` for all users

For production use the write access needs to be trimmed back to the process and admin, not all users.